# Binding LinqToSql tables to Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable, repeater, icollection

I have a class which retrieves the data from DB.

```
[Table(Name = "Ilanlar")]
public class Ilan
{

    [Column(Name="ilan_id" ,IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int M_ilan_id;

    [Column(Name="refVerenUser_id")]
    public int M_refVerenUser_id;
}
```

And i am binding the data comes from db via the class above.

```
    private void ItemsGet()
    {
        PagedDataSource objPds = new PagedDataSource();
        objPds.DataSource =  f_IlanlariGetir(CurrentPage);
        objPds.AllowPaging = true;
        objPds.PageSize = 3;

        objPds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

        rptIlanlar.DataSource = objPds;  //rptIlanlar = asp:Repeater
        rptIlanlar.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsGet();
    }

    private System.Collections.IEnumerable f_IlanlariGetir(int p)
    {
        Context context = new Context(DAO.dbYaban.ConnectionString);

        return context.GetTable<Ilan>();
    }
```

But the result is IEnumerable but i need something like DataSet. 
I'm getting this error:

[image: Cannot compute Count for a data source that does not implement ICollection.]

I found good explanation about this error, it is:

> The underlying DataSource has to support the ICollection interface in
>   order for the grid to perform automatic paging. ICollection requires a
>   class to implement a Count property. ArrayList and DataView both
>   support the interface, so you could use them as DataSources.Other classes only support the IEnumerable interface. This allows them
>   to be used as a DataSource but not as a paged data source.
>   SqlDataReader would be an example of such a class. [Reference](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t90094-system-web-httpexception-cannot-compute-count-for-a-data-source-t.html)

But i need to bind repeater with the results of linq to sql tables. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than binding directly to the query, try:

```
return context.GetTable<Ilan>().ToList();
```